# Import php file into WordPress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to import a PHP file into my new WP-Plugin. Everything works fine now. If I set the PHP file and want to include into my `Plugins/my-plugin` directory from same directory:

```
include 'foo.php';
```

But I would like to keep the PHP file in another directory (e.g. `wp-content/my-folder`).

So according to the example before, the import should look like this:

```
include '../../my-folder/foo.php';
```

but nothing of that works. I keep getting the error:

> Warning: include(): Failed opening '../../my-folder/foo.php' for
>   inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in %my-plugin-path% on
>   line 17

I also tried some variation within the way I pass the path, e.g.

```
include 'wordpress/wp-content/my-folder/foo.php';
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to call `wp-content/my-folder/my-file.php` file from `wp-content/plugins/my-plugin-folder/my-plugin-file.php`.

Two solutions from my side:

1. Using [`WP_CONTENT_DIR`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Determining_Plugin_and_Content_Directories#Constants) constant. It'll return full path of your `wp-content` folder( without trailing slash at the end ):

   ```
   include WP_CONTENT_DIR.'/my-folder/my-file.php';
   ```

   NOTE: will not work out of WordPress scope.
2. You can use [`__DIR__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) php predefined constant. It'll return the directory where your file is located( without trailing slash at the end ):

   ```
   include __DIR__.'/../../my-folder/my-file.php';
   ```

Answering to your question, what are you doing wrong. You are not using trailing slash( `/` ), at the start of your string. Your example should be:

```
include '/../../my-folder/foo.php';
```